# Mysql ignora mi orden

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy tartando de colocar un botón de borrar cuenta (esto borrará unicamente los datos de la sesión seleccionada) Pero al momento de darle la orden la ignora por completo (no salen mensajes de errores ni advertencias, directamente pasa de mi orden)

Si me pueden ayudar se los agradecería un montón. A continuación les dejo el código:

```
<?php
require '../../funcs/conexion.php';
session_start();
/*error_reporting(0);*/
$token = $_GET['token'];
$idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

$sql = "SELECT token FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$idUsuario'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_tb=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
$true_token = $row_tb['token'];

if ($true_token != $token) {
    echo "Posible intento de falsificación, redireccionando...";
}else{
echo "Bien!";
    require '../../funcs/conexion.php';
    $idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
    $sSQL="DELETE * FROM usuarios WHERE id = $idUsuario";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sSQL);
}
?>
```

Comment: Comenta el segundo `require` ya tienes conexión. Y en la sentencia `DELETE` `$idUsuario` va entre comillas sencillas, así como lo tienes en el `SELECT`.

Comment: @Sal Hola amigo, gracias por tu comentario. Ya lo intenté de ese modo y tampoco funciona :/

Comment: Hola si hiciste los cambios que te indicó @Sal, son correctos. Pero, te queda haciendo falta un detalle. `mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)` te devuelve un array con identificadores numéricos 0, 1, ... para las líneas que entrego la consulta. Como sólo esperas una, en caso de que exista: debes hacer `if(isset($row_tb[0]['token']){ $true_token = $row_tb[0]['token']; ...etc. }` Adicionalmente, la consulta puede no devolver resultados satisfactorios si ya hubo borrado y se reenvía la página.

Comment: Dinos el valor `$mysqli->error` despúes del `DELETE`.

Comment: Este es el error que devuelve poniendo el codigo de @quevedo
Warning: Illegal string offset 'token'